# GD Merging Color Mixes

Tags: gd

I'm using imagecopyresampled to merge images together.  Its working perfectly except some of the colors are strangely allocated in the wrong places.  Such that hues of one part of the image appear elsewhere.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I used imagetruecolor and made it transparent.  It fixed the issue.